# Clean Architecture - Too many Use Case Classes

Tags: java, android, use-case, clean-architecture, mvp

I'm going into **Clean Architecture** and lift my Android level from MVC to **MVP**, introducing DI with Dagger 2, Reactivity with RxJava 2, and of course Java 8.

In **MVP clean architecture** there is a **layer between the entities** (in datastores) **and the presenters** that should access them. This layer is **the "Use Case"**. An use case it's ideally an interface, that implements ONE operation on ONE entity.

I also know that Clear Architecture "**is screaming**", in sense of its projects are really highly readable as the high number of classes in them.

Now, in my project, I have something like **6 different entities**, and of course, each entity repository has **at least 4 methods** (usually get,add,delete,update) to access them.. **so, 6 * 4 = 24**.

If what I understood until now of Clean Architecture, **I will have 24 UseCase.**

This is **a lot of classes** if compared to just 6 controllers in MVC..

***Do I really have to make 24 use cases?***

I will really appreciate a clarification by someone already used it with success.

Comment: Can you post a link to a page that describes these Use Cases in detail, with example code?

Comment: I have googled a lot, but mainly: this app sample and related article: https://github.com/jshvarts/OfflineSampleApp ; this articles: https://proandroiddev.com/build-an-app-with-offline-support-exposing-network-states-1e09e138b1ed ; https://proandroiddev.com/build-an-app-with-offline-support-exposing-network-states-1e09e138b1ed ; This Talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvsOsgd0--c&feature=youtu.be ; And this articles too: https://adityaladwa.wordpress.com/2016/10/25/offline-first-reactive-android-apps-repository-pattern-mvp-dagger-2-rxjava-contentprovider/

Comment: None of the sample apps or articles you cited appear to have much to do with Clean Architecture.  They do, however, talk a lot about *reactive programming.*

Comment: The sample app is surely made with Clean Architecture paradigm.. The other articles mostly.. What do you want to see @RobertHarvey?

Comment: Read my answer below and reply.

Comment: I'm currently where you were at 3 years ago when you asked this. I get the feeling from [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/why-you-need-use-cases-interactors-142e8a6fe576) that it is fine to have use cases that merely call a repository method. "A Use Case per Repository method?
This is a very common question and the answer is: most probably yes." And he lists some benefits of these "useless use cases". He doesn't think the ViewModel should deal with repositories at all, they should only deal with use cases. In that case, use cases must be used for simple CRUD tasks.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I just want to specify that in the end I used a pattern wherein I've aggregated some methods (not much, usually just a couple, i.e. for lists: for the first data retrieval and for sync) in the same view model linked to a specific view. This reduced a bit the number of viewmodels and helped in mantaining a clean binding from views to data repositories (api and db). Feel free to make questions on other technical aspects I'll be glad to give you my best knowledge indeep. Cheers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> ***Do I really have to make 24 use cases?***

Only if everything you write is [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

Refer to the diagram below:

[image]

Your assertion is that you will have six different entities, and 4 methods (Create, Read, Update and Delete) for each entity.  But that is only true in the yellow circle in the middle of the diagram (the Entities layer). **It is pointless to create 24 methods in the Use Cases layer that merely pass through CRUD calls to the Entities layer.**

A Use Case is not "Add a Customer Record."  A Use Case is more along the lines of **"Sell an item to a customer"** (which involves Customer, Product, and Inventory entities) or **"Print an invoice"** (which involves the same entities, in addition to Invoice Header and Invoice Line Items).

When you create Use Cases, you should be thinking about *business transactions,* not *CRUD methods.*

**Further Reading**
[Aggregate - a cluster of domain objects that can be treated as a single unit](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html)

Comment: Well, I understand that the UseCases could aggregate multiple operation in its execution, by the way, as of the example, if I would have to create a CRUD for 6 entities, I will still have a lot of classes. At this point, I think this is what the clean architecture impose. Anyway, it is a good practice to try to "aggregate" multiple entities operations involved to make the UseCase cover a complete action, as a transaction, and not a single part of the operation. This is like moving some of controller logic inside the use case, but with "Single responsibility principle".

Comment: When you say "It is pointless to create 24 methods...", so would you recommend another design pattern for this goal? Like MVC? It's possible to have a project with half Clean Arch. and half MVC?

Comment: You're spending too much time thinking about patterns, practices and architecture, and not enough time thinking about basic software design.  All you need are methods that embody business practices, as I described in my answer.

Comment: Robert, I would like to embrace your suggestion but it's not enough pratically clear what to do because not all the projects just consists in complex operations, often it just is a simple crud operation. Are you suggesting to drop clean arch in favor of MVC if it mainly consist in crud ops?  Or, what do you think of wrapping multiple ops in a ManageEntityUseCase as @oopexpert wrote?

Comment: It's not a question of choosing an architecture.  My personal opinion: bare CRUD operations should talk directly to the Entity Layer.  Of course, this probably violates Clean Architecture.

Comment: Ok, and if (let's put some pepper) every operation has to be an app offline first operation (so working on local DB _and_ with network API), would you still skip the UseCases Layer or, in this case, use it with the screaming it follows?

Comment: You're kinda missing the point.  Architecture is just a means to organize code.  You solve problems by *writing code,* not wrestling with architectures.

Comment: Hey Robert, it's not so nice that you assume that I dont write code. The topic of my answer it's on architecture, and we're not on SO. Sincerely I find your last comments really misleading and deaf. The question is about UseCase in Clean Arch., not writing code. If you're trying to communicate something please explain better, because I'm missing the point of your comments. IMHO it's not possible to avoid Architecture consideration while developing software, or at least, good devs doesn't just write bunch of code. Moreover I asked a really specific question in my comment, can you answer? Thanks

Comment: The solution to the problem you posed (app offline first) doesn't really have much to do with Clean Architecture.  You won't find a solution to that problem in the Clean Architecture diagram.

Comment: Well, if you had read the article and sample project source I wrote on the comment of my answer, you would know what we are talking about.

Comment: Which one?  You linked to a lot of them, mostly discussing reactive programming.  I think we can get our discussion a bit more focused than that.  Perhaps you can quote some of the article you are referring to?

Comment: I tell you what.  Why don't you post a new question about your "app online first" issue, and I'll respond to that directly.  Make sure you include in your new question all of the information that the community needs to respond adequately, including any information you found in blog articles, etc., that you believe is relevant to your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So basically you create entity method if the method is changing self state, and you create use cases if multiple entities are involved or some external resources (DB, etc...)?

Comment: Just for giving a closure on this: I ended up organizing the code by using multiple methods inside a single UseCase, so i.e. of the question, I would have just 6 Use Case with 4 methods each.

Comment: In terms of android development, can is it a good practice to just write the business logic in the ViewModel class or do I need to create a separate class for the use case as shown in the diagram. I feel like the ViewModel belongs to the green circle.

Comment: @Lance: You haven't mentioned anything about your specific application or its unique requirements.  Like all software development questions, the one you describe is best answered within the context of your specific application.

Answer (score 4):

You are right if every CRUD-Operation is translated in one UseCase. But a UseCase may also consist of multiple CRUD-Operations.

A UseCase is a separated model gathers information from different data sources and prepares communication to data sinks. There can be multiple CRUD-Operations be involved.

So think of a UseCase where creating an invoice for a customer AND creating also the customer itself because he/she doesn't exists within the system. You have one UseCase that results in at least two Create-Operations in one transaction.

Comment: So what pattern would you reccomend for the example of the CRUD with many entities?

Comment: My personal view on this is: I have no problem to have many classes as long as they do not violate SRP (single responsibility principle). But I most of the time would redefine the Usecases "create an entity", "update an entity", "delete an entity" and "update an entity" to a simple "manage entity of type X". Often you provide a single UI to manage one entity. But that is exactly what your UseCase should define: The way to handle a beneficial load of work for your business.

Comment: Ok, so, having a Use Case that manages various different operations doesn't seem to violate SRP as it seems to just "aggregate" more different methods (and flows) in the same UseCase without that any single flow handle more than one responability... but in this way aren't we just creating a controller in place of an UseCase? .. idea .. Maybe the Use Case must be simply seen as a layer, and that layer just have to respect SRP but can also implements many methods. I would like to have a source or article about this

Comment: A Usecase IS A controller. The only difference is, that a usecase comes from the business perspective and a controller is the technical view on it. The focus of a usecase is, what is generating the business value. So a usecase is a business value driven controller implementation.

Comment: Agree, an HTTP controller is a way of managing I/O, there can also be console commands, event reactions and so on. All these I/O channels call the same usecase. 

A usecase IS a controller for business logic, it does not know about the I/O channels it was called from, but it knows how to orchestrate domain entities to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

It's assumed that clean architecture is used in business heavy applications, where use cases are mapped to business rules. In a CRUD app it's over-engineering. Here you can use facade and map requests directly to the db entity. When logic grows, refactor and extract use cases, validators, domain objects etc..

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of Use Case is wrong, Use Case is a class implementing a business rule, it does not need to be a CRUD operation, it can be a complex multi step operation

Comment: Your sentence doesn't mean a solution when you actually need to implement a wide range Crud-like operations, even your consideration may found some relation to the fact that an Use Case should observe a pattern in which we could access to a complex operation, even multi step.